# In a column of Credits, show the amount of credits for all courses for which student enlisted

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to in a column of Credits show the amount of credits for all courses for which student enlisted.

I need to modify a Contoso University app.

View:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

<h2>Students</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Student", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)

        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            First Name
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Enrollment Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            Date Of Birth
        </th>
        <th>
            Courses
        </th>
        <th>
            Credits
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMidName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnrollmentDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfBirth)
        </td>  
        <td>
            @string.Join(",", item.Enrollments.Select(e => e.Course.Title))
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

Please Help!

I dont understand how to do it!

If somebody need more details please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Contoso University, but it seems to me that you may be able to sum the credits by doing something like this:

```
item.Enrollments.Sum(e => e.Course.Credits);
```

This is untested and it's hard to know for sure if this will work without knowing how the data is structured, but I'm sure looking at the [Sum()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549069(v=vs.100).aspx) method will help you out.

Comment: 'ContosoUniversity.Models.Student' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and no extension method 'Sum' accepting a first argument of type 'ContosoUniversity.Models.Student' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Of course it doesn't! :) Updated my code to not be so errory.

Answer (score 1):

@item.Enrollments.Sum(e => e.Course.Credits)